# How can check the table records

Tags: android

I have a table and i want to check that whether it is empty or it has some records..
How can i check?

Comment: elaborate your question, what type of database you are using?

Comment: A table? A table of what sort? TableLayout? SQL table? Be more specific please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL? You can use

```
select * from table
```

or

```
describe table
```